# How to enqueue functions in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase functions and am trying to enqueue a function from within a RTDB onWrite trigger, so far I either get errors or nothing happens, I also cannot find anything useful online, and even the firebase docs aren't much of a help...

This is my Realtime DB trigger function which is supposed to enqueue the firebase function.

Attempt #1

```
exports.onUserBasketUpdated = functions
  .region("my-region")
  .database.ref("/path/{uid}")
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    const queue = getFunctions(admin.app, "my-region").taskQueue(
      "expireUserBasket"
    );
    await queue.enqueue(
      {
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        dispatchDeadlineSeconds: 60 * 1, // 1 minute
      }
    );
    return { data: "ok" };
  });
```

Attempt #1 Results:
Error: "ReferenceError: queue is not defined"

Attempt #2:

```
exports.onUserBasketUpdated = functions
  .region("my-region")
  .database.ref("/path/{uid}")
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    await functions
      .taskQueue(`locations/my-region/functions/expireUserBasket`)
      .enqueue({ message: "hello" });
    return { data: "ok" };
  });
```

Attempt #2 Result:
Error: "TypeError: functions.taskQueue is not a function"

The function which I am trying to enqueue:

```
exports.expireUserBasket = functions
  .region("my-region")
  .runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 120 })
  .tasks.taskQueue({
    retryConfig: {
      maxAttempts: 5,
      minBackoffSeconds: 60,
    },
    rateLimits: {
      maxConcurrentDispatches: 6,
    },
  })
  .onDispatch(async (data) => {
    console.info("data from the scheduled function", data);
  });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are getting a queue not defined error, you've probably missed [this step in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions#deploying_the_task_queue_function) (emphasis mine):

> #### Deploying the task queue function
>
> Deploy task queue function using the Firebase CLI:
>
> ```
> $ firebase deploy --only functions:backupApod
> ```
>
> **When deploying a task queue function for the first time, the CLI creates a task queue in Cloud Tasks with options (rate limiting and retry) specified in your source code.**

So before trying to deploy and test `onUserBasketUpdated`, deploy only the `expireUserBasket` function:

```
$ firebase deploy --only functions:expireUserBasket
```

Comment: That is actually a valid point, I haven't followed the docs correctly and deployed all of them at once, I am using around 4 cloud functions. that did not fix the issue though, it stills throws the error "Queue does not exist", I am worried I am not understanding this feature correctly, do I need to set anything up in [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview) ??

Comment: On deployment, deploying the task queue function should create the required queues. Did the deployment succeed? What task queue was created in your Google Cloud project?

Comment: Thanks for responding, I really do appreciate it. Ok that makes sense then, it should be done automatically. I will recreate the project again after work to make sure no steps were skipped and will update this question...

Comment: Yes, seems like that have fixed the issue.... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data) is pretty good on this feature. Example code is provided.

In terms of actually calling a particular function, do that directly in your function's code. That's how you would call it.

I don't believe the [Enqueue functions with Cloud Tasks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions) is utilized in your use case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I have followed the guide and used their code yet I still get errors in the console. 'Error: Queue does not exist.
    at FirebaseFunctionsError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)'

Comment: There should be no queue. You code what happens. You have installed the admin sdk and are basically scripting server side. That's where you define the behavior you want. call it with the `exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/messages/{pushId}/original')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {`

Comment: I don't understand, I want to enqueue a function which will run on a schedule, as per the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions. The RTDB Trigger I am using works perfectly fine. Not sure how else to phrase my question Ronnie.

Comment: If you want to do something in response to a RTDB event, then `You can make Firebase Realtime Database changes via the DataSnapshot or via the Admin SDK.` ([source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)). If you want to do something on scheduled intervals use `functions.pubsub.schedule().onRun()` ([source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)).